# Prompt user in Javascript on user click

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller, pageblocktable

I have a pageblock table. Upon click the add button, it will trigger the add() method on my controller and return the boolean 'BO' value, I would like to check if boolean is true, there will be a javascript display which will prompt user to continue. However, I'm unable to display the msg. Why is that so? But the msg will be displayed when I remove the  if('{!BO}' == true).. Is there something wrong with my if statement? Anyone?

```
<apex:column>
                <script>

            function confirmBO(){
                if('{!BO}' == true){
                  return confirm('Are you sure you want to continue?');

                }
            }
          </script>
                 <apex:commandButton action="{!add}" value="Add" oncomplete="if(!confirmBO()) return false;"/>

                </apex:column>
```

Comment: Try doing an alert({!BO}); before your if statement, so that you can see the value you are comparing to true.

Comment: You are leaving yourself vulnerable to XSS by merging in the value that way. Always use `JSENCODE` or a similar encoding function to protect yourself!

Comment: @TCSutton ive tried your method. it display the value.. but it does'nt go inside the if block

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'm sorry i dont und what you mean, btw im new to salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a matter of data types... I guess it will work in either way: if you remove the quotes around your boolean variable or if you write true in quotes

Comment: That should only be the case with `===` no? Which should be used in this case anyway.

Comment: @AdrianLarson === operator do not perform type conversion. It performs a rather more restrictive check. alert('true' == true); // false
        alert('true' === true); // false
        alert(true == 1);        // true
        alert(true === 1);      // false

Comment: Further clarification could be found at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem as to do with the incorrect use of the "oncomplete" property, which is intended for use with ajax calls and seems out of place.  I don't believe you ever get to the point where your oncomplete handler is invoked -- that is why you never see the confirm dialog.

If you want the prompt to appear before you take an action, you should probably call your confirm() javascript method in an onclick() handler instead.

For example:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!add}" value="Add" onclick="return confirmBO();" />
```

I would also update the confirmBO method to always return either true or false depending on if you want the operation to proceed by default or not.  I presume the BO controller method returns a boolean variable.

```
function confirmBO(){
    if({!BO}){
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to continue?');
    } else {
        return false;  // do not invoke action by default
    }
}
```

The onclick handler will invoke first and the apex action will only be fired if the onclick handler/logic returns true.  I believe this is your desired behavior.